# Prevent iTunes opening on Play/Pause button in macOS

Tags: mac, itunes, macos-mojave

I'm trying to prevent the iTunes app opening every time I press the Play/Pause key on my Mac's keyboard.

If I'm using Spotify or another music app, that key should control the active audio being played.

I've installed a lot of apps but none are working.

Answer (score 1):

1. From the Apple menu, choose “Restart…” > “Restart“.
2. Simultaneously press and hold the “Command” and “R” buttons. (This will start you in Recovery Mode)
3. Type the following to disable the System Integrity Protection and press enter:

> csrutil disable

4. Then restart and let the login proceed as normal. Once you’re in, run the following command to disable the f#?! iTunes. This will prevent you opening iTunes

> sudo chmod -x /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes

5. Reenable the System Integrity Protection to the previous status (enabled):

> csrutil enable

To disable the 3 music keys is this command:

> launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist

Bye bye iTunes :)

Comment: Note that the `launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist` command must be performed without the System Integrity Protection enabled

Comment: Re last step: Doesn't this just disable those buttons? What if we still want to use them with other apps

Comment: Yes, OP made it clear that they want to use the keys with other apps, so this is not a valid answer.