# Prevent Music.app from starting on F8 (play) button (osx 10.15)

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, itunes, music, macos-catalina

I want to control Spotify using the function key media shortcuts, but Music.app opens instead of Spotify playing (even though Spotify is open already.

How can I prevent Music.app from listening to the shortcuts? Alternatively, how can I delete the app?

I have tried all the tricks that used to work on iTunes before 10.15 came out but they no longer work.

**The advice provided in this ticket is outdated now and does not work:  [Prevent iTunes opening on Play/Pause button in macOS](https://superuser.com/questions/1383264/prevent-itunes-opening-on-play-button-in-macos-mojave-stop-play-pause-button)**

This ticket is about Music.app and not iTunes and OSX 10.15 does not work like the one referenced in that ticket

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent iTunes opening on play button in macos Mojave . Stop play/pause button](https://superuser.com/questions/1383264/prevent-itunes-opening-on-play-button-in-macos-mojave-stop-play-pause-button)